# Does Stone-Weierstrass hold for sets of functions that only separate points on a dense subspace?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Supose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff topological space and $Y \subseteq X$ a dense subset. If $S$ is a set of functions in $C(X)$ such that separates points in $Y$ then the Stone-Weierstrass theorem still hold?

Comment: If memory serves, Stone-Weierstrass for $C(X\rightarrow\mathbb{C})$ requires self-adjointness as well, which suggests that your conjecture is false. But I'm having trouble constructing a counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

No, this never works unless $Y$ is all of $X$.  Indeed, suppose $x\in X\setminus Y$ and $y\in Y$.  Consider the subalgebra $A$ of $C(X)$ consisting of all functions $f$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.  Then $A$ is a closed *-subalgebra of $C(X)$ and it separates points of $Y$, but it is not all of $C(X)$.